# Ensure all data was received

Tags: c#, winsock

I am following [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but I am running into a problem.  The sequence of my client/server connection goes like this:

> 1. Server is always listening for new clients
> 2. Client initiates connection
> 3. Server sends a small packet with connection information (9 bytes), client receives
> 4. Client sends response connection information, server receives
> 5. More back and forth with packets

My code is getting stuck during step 3 because the first call to `BeginReceive` is actually receiving all the data at once, but it goes into another call to `BeginReceive` even though there is no more data to get.  I am using a custom server implementation that already functions communicating in this same fashion with an iOS application.

Is there a simple check I can perform to see if there is indeed more data to be received on the socket?

Here is my implementation of the receive callback function, the start receive function is identical:

```
    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( "Received data" );
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the remote device.
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                //First pass reads all 9 bytes the server sent
                Console.WriteLine ( "Received bytes: {0}", bytesRead );
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.ms.Write(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                // Get the rest of the data.
                //Gets stuck in this call because there is no more data to receive
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine ( "Received all data? {0}", state.ms.Length );
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
                if ( state.ms.Length > 0 )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ( "Received whole packet" );
                    MyPacketInfo.MyPacket receivedPacket = MyPacketInfo.MyPacket.packetFromMemoryStream ( state.ms );

                    if ( receivedPacket != null )
                    {
                        state.caller.ReceivedPacket ( receivedPacket, client );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine ( "Received bad packet!" );
                    }
                }

                // Signal that all bytes have been received.
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"Is there a simple check I can perform to see if there is indeed more data to be received on the socket?"_ - no. Your program needs to determine this, based on the protocol in use and data already received and sent.

Comment: @CodeCaster  Examining my iOS code, I can see that I check after each receive if the stream still has bytes available, there is no such feature in C#?

Comment: There is [`Socket.Available`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.available(v=vs.110).aspx) but despite its name it does not do what you want. TCP doesn't know if your server is sending data, it only knows what it has received.

Comment: @CodeCaster In using sockets, is it safe to assume that if I did not receive the full buffer's amount of data, or that `Socket.Available` is false, that there is no more data currently coming across?  Assuming I have this Transmit/Acknowledge type of communication sequence.